# Elasticsearch snapshot IN_PROGRESS for long time, delete snapshot is also not working

Tags: elasticsearch, snapshot

I'm using Elasticsearch 5.1.1 and we have a daily snapshot process running. The last snapshot have been created few days ago and its status is still *IN_PROGRESS*.

I tried to delete via snapshot api but it fails. Also I'm unable to take new snapshot due to snapshot in progress exception. Please help me to resolve this issue.

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Snapshots should be cancellable through the tasks API. Did you try using the tasks API in order to cancel it? see here: https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/elasticsearch/reference/current/tasks.html#task-cancellation

Comment: I have tried using task API but the task is **"cancellable" : false** of type.

Comment: OK, so instead of using the tasks API, you can just delete the snapshot, even when it is in progress. From Elastic docs: "If the deleted snapshot operation is executed while the snapshot is being created the snapshotting process will be aborted and all files created as part of the snapshotting process will be cleaned. Therefore, the delete snapshot operation can be used to cancel long running snapshot operations that were started by mistake." - see here: https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/elasticsearch/reference/current/modules-snapshots.html

Comment: I have tried deleting the snapshot but it failed. It's a bug in Elasticsearch and a full cluster restart will sort out this - here is the link : https://discuss.elastic.co/t/elasticsearch-snapshot-in-progress-for-a-long-time-the-delete-snapshot-api-is-also-not-working/202623/2?u=nisham